# Flat directory structure for multimodules?

Tags: sbt

Is it possible, with SBT to use a flat directory structure for multimodules?

That is, instead of having:

```
- parent
  |- child_a
  |- child_b
```

to simply have:

```
- parent
- child_a
- child_b
```

I have tried the later and configured the parent `project/Build.scala` with:

```
lazy val child_a = Project(id = "child_a",
    base = file("../child_a"))
```

But when doing an sbt command, like `sbt package`, I get to following error:

```
[error] java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Directory D:\src\child_a is not contained in build root D:\src\parent
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Right.  You can use source dependencies, but those are a bit heavier footprint.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is `ProjectRef`.

`Directory ... not contained in build root ...` is an issue for `Project` - **but not for `ProjectRef`**. If You switch to `ProjectRef` it will go. If you define in main project's `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val root = (project in file ("."))
    .aggregate(helper_library)
    .dependsOn(helper_library)

lazy val helper_library = ProjectRef(file("../helper_library"), "helper_library")
```

then the `helper_library` and the main project are siblings regarding the directory structure - as you wished in your question - at the same time, the main project aggregates to, and depends on `helper_library`.